# MySQL SELECT on multiple FULLTEXT indexes. Extremely slow results

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, query-optimization, database-indexes

10 million rows. MySQL server V. 5.7 Two indexes called "tagline" and "experience".

This statement takes < 1 second:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pa
    WHERE MATCH(tagline) AGAINST('"developer"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This statement also takes < 1 second:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pa
    WHERE MATCH(experience) AGAINST('"python"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This combined statement takes 30 seconds:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pa
    WHERE MATCH(tagline) AGAINST('"developer"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND MATCH(experience) AGAINST('"python"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Similar problem outlined here. Essentially slight alterations to fulltext match make it useless:
https://medium.com/hackernoon/dont-waste-your-time-with-mysql-full-text-search-61f644a54dfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with Sphinx. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OP0c26k_iQc

Fairly easy way of upgrading the capabilities of MySQL without committing to a new stack.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last one to

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pa
    WHERE MATCH(tagline, experience) AGAINST('+developer +python' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

*and* add

```
FULLTEXT(tagline, experience)
```

(I am assuming you are using Engine=InnoDB.)

Be aware that when using `MATCH`, it is performed first; anything else.  In your case, one `MATCH` was performed, then it struggled to perform the other, there is way to run a second `MATCH` efficiently.

Comment: You actually responded to a similar question that I posted nearly a year ago. The problem with this approach for me is that it does not distinguish between fields so "PHP" in the tagline also matches "PHP" in experience. Hence you need an additional LIKE query to filter, which kills the speed in my case. As you said, back in the good old days, I need some sort of full-text search system. Researching Sphinx right now. If you could point me in the direction of an even easier and quicker solution for my fairly narrow use-case, that would be sincerly appreciated.

Comment: @NedHulton - What is the goal of the combined set?  _Both_ word in _both_ columns?  Both in either?  Either in both?  Or something else?

Comment: $tagline in the tagline column AND experience in the $experience column.

Comment: @NedHulton - Not practical.